# Why does JSON.parse(null) return null?

Tags: javascript

Whenever you pass in `null` to `JSON.parse`:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(null))
```

It returns null, but I can't find any docs on why this is the case. Is there a reason why this returns null?

Other things to note:

- This *may* be due to type conversion, as passing `JSON.parse("null")` also returns null, but is this specified anywhere?

Comment: Closely related: [Shouldn't JSON.parse(null) and JSON.parse(false) throw exceptions?](/q/53095713/4642212).

Comment: It’s a bit strange to post a self-answer which links to the spec while the question states _“I can't find any docs”_…

Comment: @SebastianSimon: it was to cut short a discussion under [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914838/2159528). ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [`JSON.parse(text\[,receiver\])` specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-json.parse), where:

- Let *`jsonString`* be ? *`ToString(text)`*.

It is converting the text to a string (`null` -> `"null"`). This is then passed to the internal JSON parser

Once it is in the parser, `JSON.parse` not only works with full JSON structures, but also JSON values such as `number`, `string`, and *`null`*.

Therefore, `null` is parsed as the `null` value, and returned straight back.